# WPF - Hit Testing Rendered Pixel of Characters

Tags: wpf, character, pixel, hittest

Is there a way to hit test the pixels of characters in wpf? I want to be able to get a hit for the dot of the character 'i' but don't get a hit when I click the space between the dot and the line of 'i'. I tried to do it using DrawingContext.DrawText method and but when I hit test against the resulting DrawingVisual, which contains the text, using VisualTreeHelper.HitTest method it doesn't differentiate the space and the black pixels of the character. It gives a hit for every point in the bounding box of a character. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. To do this you have to go to lower level to GlyphRunDrawing. Use the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getdrawing.aspx) and substitute GeometryDrawing with GlyphRunDrawing. Then get the GeometryGroup, which contains each character as Geometry, and do the hit testing with the code:

```
GeometryGroup ggroup = (GeometryGroup)((GlyphRunDrawing)drawing).GlyphRun.BuildGeometry();
if(ggroup.FillContains(pt))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Contains point " + pt.ToString());
}
```